# Possible bug (?) xsockets.net console server

Tags: c#, sockets, xsockets.net

I'm trying to start development on xsockets.net service. 
My server doesn't want to recognize any of CustomController implementation for a Console Application (server). Everything works fine in Web project.
I've noticed that XSocketPlugins property contains a list of plugins. My plugin is not on a list for console App and is registered for Web.
The source code is simple like in ReadMe.txt

```
    using (var container = XSockets.Plugin.Framework.Composable.GetExport<IXSocketServerContainer>())
    {             
      container.StartServers();
      container.OnServerClientConnection+=container_OnServerClientConnection
      Console.ReadLine();<br/>
    }

    Defining new controller

    public class CustomController1 : XSocketController
    {
      public void OnMessage(...) 
        { 
          //do stuff
        }
    }
```

I'm able to connect to Generic controller using C# client and JS client.
Any ideas?

Env: Windows7 64-bit, VS2012, .NET 4.0

Comment: Additional strange behaviour: I started testing xsockets.net in Web as it works. But I cannot connect using XSockets Client library.
I use same connection string: "ws://localhost:4502/mycontroller and after .Open() the property IsConnected is false. Also for Generic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the bug is described here: [known-issues](http://xsockets.net/docs/known-issues) and the work around is also described.

Regarding the comment, please post the code you use to connect with the Client API and maybe I can see something in there. There should not be any problems connecting from the clients API.

Comment: Thank you. I went back to sit with the problem and Controller referenced as external dll works fine. That's ok for me. I still cannot connect C# Client. My code is very simple:
[code]
var client = new XSocketClient("ws://127.0.0.1:4502/xrouter", "*");
client.Open();//after Open client.IsConnected is false<br/>

//this loop was for testing purposes only<br/>
while (client.IsConnected == false)<br/>
{<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<br/>
}<br/>
//after 50ms the flag IsConnected is true but it is not connected to server.

Comment: Everything is Async so you cant just check status right after calling Open. Use the open event (see http://xsockets.net/docs/c-client-api#open)

Comment: OK, I found the problem. I was trying to use Client in Windows Forms app and I declared XSockets.Client.XSocketClient as variable in Form. In OnLoad event I was trying to create connection. Now I did the same in static Main() and it just works. 
Does it mean that that client must be initiated in main or static method? Strange, don't you think? If you need exact source, please let me now. But I think you can replicate it now.

Comment: No, you do not have to create the instance in a static method. Personally I do not use WinForms, but I have done tests without issues.